# Laravel Elastic Beanstalk app deployed in CodePipeline giving 500 SERVER ERROR

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I've created a Laravel app locally.  (This is working fine)

After, deployed that app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk with a .zip file. (This is working fine)

[image]

Then, created a [simple pipeline using AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/continuous-deployment-pipeline/) to grab data from a particular GitHub repo and deploy to that specific AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment. I see that any push I make to that particular repo, the CodePipeline does then deploy to that particular AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment.

The problem is that the instance now has

[image]

with the following Recent Event

> Environment health has transitioned from Warning to Severe. 100.0 % of
> the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx. ELB processes are not healthy
> on all instances. Application restart completed 42 seconds ago and
> took 7 seconds. ELB health is failing or not available for all
> instances. One or more TargetGroups associated with the environment
> are in a reduced health state: - awseb-AWSEB-CVIEEN5EVRFC - Warning

and if I go to its URL I get a

> 500 | SERVER ERROR

[image]

- Deleted the .zip file from the root of the repo as that could've been causing a conflict. It didn't solve.

[image]

- Checked the Full Logs but couldn't spot anything useful.

Comment: Can you download the artifact/zip that gets deployed by CP to your EB and inspect it to check if it has all files that you  require?

Comment: @Marcin if I go to Application versions can see that version label but clicking in the source there's nothing in there apart from a file named `S40pAMw` with nothing readable in it. Nothing in CP artifacts either

Comment: `S40pAMw` is probably the zip file. Just add the zip extension. You can also got to CP artifact bucket.

Comment: @Marcin right, it's a .zip file. I can see right away it doesn't have the .env file

Comment: @Marcin and the problem is that it's a file that's not being added to GitHub. I'll add that and it's likely to fix the problem

Comment: @Marcin it works now. Please write as an answer and I'll include relevant extra info + screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **missing** `.env` file in the deployment package/artifact that CodePipeline deploys. This was caused by the file not being committed into the GitHub repository.

To determine the cause, the **CodePipeline's artifact** was inspected. The artifact can be found in CodePipeline's bucket or in EB Application versions (in the Source column) and it is an objects a random name without an extension. In OP's case it was `S40pAMw`. It should be noted that this object is just a `zip` file without extension. To inspect it content, adding the extension to the download object allowed for straight forward opening of the `zip` archive.

(Please see @JackPrice-Burns answer for alternative way of dealing with env variables).

The **solution** was to commit the missing file into the repository. Once that was done, the CodePipeline was triggered

[image]

and once the deployment finished the Health of the Elastic Beanstalk instance changed to Ok

[image]

and the 500 | SERVER ERROR was now gone

[image]

Comment: You should not be committing the .env or any secrets to GitHub, AWS has a way to add environment variables without doing this.

Also you should not commit the composer vendor folder to GitHub either, you can add a build step to your pipeline where you can run composer install before you send it to elastic beanstalk.

Comment: @JackPrice-Burns I don't question the architecture, but answer to the issue posted - why CP deployment did not work.

Comment: However, you then proceeded to suggest a bad practice, advising to commit the .env file to the repo. This should not have been suggested, if this repo is public their secrets are now publicly available. Also adding environment variables to the elastic beanstalk config is not changing the infrastructure

Comment: @JackPrice-Burns I don't suggest anything. This was based on the comments.

Comment: Okay fair point, sorry, however if someone comes to this post with a similar issue they're going to see an answer which says to commit the .env (maybe tweak your post)

Comment: @JackPrice-Burns No problem. I updated my answer to refer to yours.

Comment: Another of the things which leads me to have this answer as accepted was the contribution to finding what the problem really was. That's something that could also be included in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

This issue specifically was caused by missing environment variables.

It is BAD practice to commit .env or any files containing secrets to GitHub or any other source control system.

- First of all, if that repository is public in any way, all of the secrets are now also public, database credentials, encryption keys, AWS access credentials.
- Secondly, a common attack vector is the .git folder, and the underlying source control repository. Potentially a malicious user (if they found the source control details) could gain access to your secrets if your GitHub (or other accounts) were compromised.
- Thirdly, if you would like to setup multiple environments for your code, a production / develop / local environment for example. You now can't easily change these environment variables on a per environment basis as they're committed directly to the repository.

In the ElasticBeanstalk console you can go to Configuration -> Software and add environment variables at the bottom of the page (screen shot attached). These environment variables will be picked up by Laravel. Set all variables that are in the .env on that settings page and do not commit the .env.

[image: elastic beanstalk console]

Another good practice to follow is not committing your vendor folder. AWS CodePipeline allows you to create another step which can build your source code. This build step can take in your source control code, run composer install (to generate the vendor folder) and then send that to Elastic Beanstalk for deployment.

- Firstly, committing the vendor folder drastically increases the size of your repository and how long it takes to clone your repository.
- Secondly, merging code from different branches can become difficult if you're dealing with the whole vendor folder as well which can become thousands of files and millions of lines of code.
- Thirdly, if you would like to track how much work has actually been done for your repo on a per contributor basis, it becomes difficult because if someone commits a vendor folder change, they will commit whole packages which they didn't code themselves.

Comment: One thing to note. I couldn't had all variables present in the .env file right away. Had to delete `MAIL_ENCRYPTION, APP_ENV=local, PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1, DB_PORT=3306, MAIL_HOST=mailhog, PUSHER_APP_KEY=, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=` and only then was able to apply the changes.

Comment: Not sure why you had to delete these environment variables, none of these should be reserved by elastic beanstalk. Only thing I can suggest is ensuring the value field doesn't have any incompatible characters. You can find individual tutorials how to use each AWS service (ElasticBeanstalk, CodePipeline, CodeBuild) on https://aws.training/ for free

Comment: not sure either but an error was showing up that in the end included `Not a List of Key/Value pairs.`.